# Prevent users from updating a value in a text box after it is selected from an autocompleting list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a text box which is an autocomplete field allowing the user to enter values into it but user is able to change the value after selecting from the list of populated values. 
In order to avoid that, I tried using combobox, but combobox doesn't seem to work with input and it only works with select. In my case, I cannot use select as the values coming up are from a database table and not any predefined values.

Is there any way to avoid users from selecting any values other than the ones in the autopopulating list into the text field? I beleive we can do this with jQuery, as I am not having enough knowledge on jQuery, I am unable to check any solution for it.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: well in order to trigger the auto complete, you have to start typing something anyway no? so how exactly do you want to prevent the users from selecting something else, cant they just tpe something that has no auto complete results and leave it like that? can you be more specific as to what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: You can use php to generate as many select as you need

Comment: the users enter it from the list which comes up when he enters 2-3 characters. But the value he enters should be something from those values and not any modified value. Incase the user tampers with any selected value, he shouldnt be allowed.

Comment: I have read that we can use ui event to check if value is altered aftering entering and it worked for a few users, but its not working for me. Not sure if i am using this in correct way: <input id="employee" name="emp_name" type="text" onChange="javascript:function(event,ui){if (ui.item==null) {alert ('hi.please select valid emp name');}};" onKeyPress="<for autocomplete>" onFocus="<for autocomplete>"/>

Comment: _“In my case, I cannot use select as the values coming up are from a database table and not any predefined values”_ – if you can get the values for any kind of autocomplete functionality, then you can get them to populate a select with options as well. // For a given set of fixed values, and an app that won’t accept any other user input than that, a select field or a number of checkboxes/radio buttons would be the obvious UX choice. […]

Comment: […] If the number of values is too large (and that’s why you want an input with autocomplete), then set the `readonly` attribute after the user has made their choice. But keep in mind that you should also allow the user to change their choice (even if it’s just because they accidentally chose the wrong option) – see if triggering the autocomplete script still works if readonly is set.

Comment: Make the submitting of the form only possible with a value from the list (you can store it in a nameless hidden input and compare them, for example)